# Animate navigation when scrolled passed a point

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate (slide in from the top) my navigation menu and it is triggered by the scroll() function. If the users scrolls passed 40, the navigation menu needs to animate. When the users scrolls less then 40, the navigation menu has to animate again (slide back up).

It does work with the code in the jsFiddle below but when a user scrolls from above 40 to the bottom, the function is called every time he scrolls so the navigation menu slides down very slowly and not smoothly.

Does someone know how to fix this of use another function then scroll()? Thanks!

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gffmQ/) and below is the jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /** HIDE MENU **/
    $(".menu").css("margin-top", "-88px");

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var verschil = ($(window).scrollTop() / 5);

        if (verschil > 40) 
        $('.menu').animate({'margin-top': '0px' }, {duration: 500, queue: false});

        else if (verschil < 40)
        $('.menu').animate({'margin-top': '-88px' }, {duration: 500, queue: false});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these 2 control variables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /** HIDE MENU **/
    $(".menu").css("margin-top", "-88px");
    var mustSlideDown = true;
    var mustSlideUp = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var verschil = ($(window).scrollTop() / 5);

        if (verschil > 40 && mustSlideDown)  {

            $('.menu').animate({'margin-top': '0px' }, {duration: 500, queue: false});
            mustSlideDown = false;
            mustSlideUp = true;
        }
        else if (verschil < 40 && mustSlideUp) {

            $('.menu').animate({'margin-top': '-88px' }, {duration: 500, queue: false});
            mustSlideUp = false;
            mustSlideDown = true;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This seems to be working very well, clever solution! Thanks a lot!